# How to tokenize a 'Python Pandas' 'Series' of strings

Tags: python, pandas

hello I am trying to convert into tokens of every content of "Chat" which is a column in my pandas dataframe having a length of 1000

```
text=df["Chat"]
words=text.split()
tokens=word_tokenize(text)
tokens=[i.lower() for i in words]
table=str.maketrans("","",string.punctuation)
stripped=[i.translate(table) for i in tokens]
words=[words for words in stripped if words.isalpha()]
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
words=[w for w in words if not w in stop_words]
print(words)
```

following error msg shoes -
"AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split' .

but when I uses iloc to slice it works fine.

```
text=df["Chat"].iloc[0]
words=text.split()
tokens=word_tokenize(text)
tokens=[i.lower() for i in words]
table=str.maketrans("","",string.punctuation)
stripped=[i.translate(table) for i in tokens]
words=[words for words in stripped if words.isalpha()]
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
words=[w for w in words if not w in stop_words]
print(words)
```

it works perfectly fine and the output is what i want i.e. a list of tokens.
i want to convert every item of chat in tokens.

Comment: split is a method for strings, to use it on a Series you need to call Series.apply(split)

Comment: Use `text.str.split()`, split on `iloc[0]` work because its being applied over a string. But when you do `text.split()` its being applied over a series. And series doesn't have that method because a series can have any datatype as data.

Answer (score 0):

your dataframe is called df, this is a dataframe object.

when you do `df["Chat"]` you are indexing into the pandas series object Chat.

You are then applying a python function `.split()`, but a pandas series has no such attribute, therefore you are getting an attribute error.

`.split()` is primarily for strings I believe.

when you are doing `df["Chat"].iloc[0]` you are taking your dataframe, indexing into the pandas series Chat, and then indexing into the first value, and then using `.split()`.

**Option 1:**

if you want to apply a function to each cell in a pandas series you can use `.apply()` or lambdas I believe.

Here is the doc for `.apply()` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html

so it seems you should be able to do `df["Chat"].apply(split)`

**Option 2:**

Pandas also allows you to use `.str` which then allows you to apply functions or other things that strings can have. so you can try `df["Chat"].str.split()`

Comment: option 1 says name 'split' is not defined and option 2 gives the same error saying 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'